# google siganute make one image have two links

Tags: html, css, gmail, email-templates

so i have this image [image]

so that each side of the image but please note it is one whole image
has a differnt url
so when i click on me it should go to `google.com` and when i click on you it should go to `youtube.com`
and i want that to work on gmail signature i did something like this but it doesn't seem to work when i paste it in gmail signature

```
<style>
      #link1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 257px;
  height: 133px;
  float: left;
      }
      #link2{
        width: 257px;
      height: 133px;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 282px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a style="" href="google.com">
      <span id="link1"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="youtube.com">
      <span id="link2"></span>
    </a>
     <img src="images/Image.png" alt="">
```

the image is displayed in gmail signature but its not clickable

Comment: User inline CSS for emails. Margins and position dont have same support across email clients. Your coding will have to be tables and two images. Even background images dont work the way its supposed to on all email clients.

Answer (score 0):

You must use background-image.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3SHH.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.link {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="google.com" class="link"></a>
  <a href="youtube.com" class="link"></a>
</div>
```